# List of all things that extend your life

Tags: talmud-gemara

Does anyone have a list of things it says in the Gemara that specifically מאריכין לו ימיו ושנותיו? Not sure if such a list exists but if not, can people just name whatever places they know of in Shas that say this.

For example, 2 that come to mind are in Berachot where it says whoever does shnayim mikra has his days extended, and it also says this by one who extends his Amen

Comment: Weeeel, if you want to get technical, aaand, you think you’re from עילי הכהן, the Gemara in Rosh Hashanah says that learning Torah, and doing גמילת חסדים helps. Abaye was from עילי and learned Torah and did גמילת חסדים, and he lived till 60, even though those from עילי only lived till about 18.

Comment: @hayam lol not that technical, just anything with the exact language of מאריכין that chazal advise us to do

Comment: There's a list in מסכת מגילה but I don't know where exactly

Comment: @zunior yeah I know what you’re referring to it’s where all the rabbis tell their students what they did for a long life.

Comment: The two I remember are 1. no nicknames amd 2. No using Shuls as a shortcut when walking